# Is there a way to convert a python dictionary with some values on GPU memory to have everything on main memory?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I have a Deep Learning (Using PyTorch) model whose output is given in dictionary format. The dictionary has multiple arrays as values and all these arrays are on GPU memory (torch.tensors with device = 'cuda'). Is there any way to move every array in the dictionary to main memory in one go?

My current way of going about this is to write a loop and re-write the GPU arrays into variables and use those, but that seems quite ineffecient. My essential goal is to further process the outputs in a multi-threaded manner, but since these arrays are on GPU memory mutliple threads cannot access them at once.

Would appreciate any sort of help or suggestions for this!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [dictionary comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/dictionary-comprehension) on the output dictionary `out`:

```py
out = {k: v.to(device='cpu', non_blocking=True) for k, v in out.items()}
```

If `out` has some elements that are not tensors, you can use:

```py
out = {k: v.to(device='cpu', non_blocking=True) if hasattr(v, 'to') else v for k, v in out.items()}
```